# Написан код для быстрой сортировки с подсчётом кол-ва итераций и времени, за которое эти итерации выполняются. Но в итоге ошибка. Как пофиксить?

Tags: python, сортировка

[image: Код и ошибка, которую он выдаёт]
Подскажите пожалуйста, что поменять, чтобы заработало?

```
    import random
import time

def sort_two(mas):
    l = 0
    r = len(mas)-1
    f = l+(r-l)/2
    x = mas[f]
    i = l
    j = r
    while (i <= j):
        while(mas[i]<x):
            i=i+1
        while(mas[j]>x):
            j=j-1
        if(i <= j):
            (mas[i],mas[j]) = (mas[j],mas[i])
            i=i+1
            j=j-1
    if (i < r):
        sort_two(mas,i,r)
    if (l < j):
        sort_two(mas,l,j)
    return mas
    
print("Введите кол-во чисел в массиве:")
mas = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    a = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    mas.append(a)
print("Массив до сортировки:")
print(mas)
print("Массив после сортировки:")
k = 0
start = time.time()
print(sort_two(mas))
stop = time.time()
print ("время", (stop - start)*1000)
```

Comment: Код картинкой? Вы бы ещё напели его.

Comment: за код картинкой я обычно прошу знакомую бабку чтоб она поворожила на засыхание кончика у автора  такого вопроса

Comment: Добавил код))))

Comment: `f = l+(r-l)   //   2`

Comment: Но дальше всё-равно будут проблемы, потому что у вашей функции один аргумент, а вы дальше вызываете её с тремя аргументами `sort_two(mas,i,r)`